# Template function argument in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I was wondering why below code does not compile with gcc (4.6.3) while it works perfectly fine using cl. I can obviously compile it with gcc by removing the template argument of the `DoSomething` function. Nonetheless I'd like to understand why the syntax below is not correct.

Thanks for any hints.

```
template <class T>
class Base {
public:
    template <class B>
    struct Var1 {
        B var1_var;
    };

    Base() {};
    ~Base() {};
    template <class V> void DoSomething(V val) {
        std::cout << val.var1_var << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
public:
    Derived() {};
    ~Derived() {};
    void Test() {
        typename Base<T>::template Var1<int> val;
        val.var1_var = 5;
        Base<T>::DoSomething<typename Base<T>::template Var1<int> >(val);   //error: expected ‘(’ before ‘>’ token
    }
};

int main(int, char**) {
    Derived<double> bla;
    bla.Test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get when you use gcc? Please help the community to help you, by providing as much information as possible in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Test` is a `nondependant name` (it does not involve `T`) so the compiler won't look in `dependant` base class while looking for the function `Dosomething`.
You can solve this problem like you did (with 0x499602D2 's answer), but it will not allow virtual dispatch mechanism. You can solve this just by using `this->DoSomething(val)` also, that will enable virtual dispatch.

More information [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need another `template`:

```
Base<T>::template DoSomething<typename Base<T>::template Var1<int> >(val);
//       ^^^^^^^^
```

Update: You also don't need to provide the template parameter. You can allow template argument deduction to do it for you:

```
DoSomething(val);
```

Comment: Template deduction is what I meant with 'removing the template argument of the `DoSomething` function' in my original question. Sorry for not being precise.